# php in function what's better: static var or database query

Tags: php, function, variables, optimization, static

I'm working with a php program that loops through a function.

Right now this function runs a bunch of queries every time it's called.

I'm thinking of setting static variables, run each query once, then save it to the static var.
(of course I would check if the ids being passed to the query are the same.)

I'm planning on redoing the whole program, I just want to do a few quick patches so the program shouldn't be as slow, so I'm wondering:

Would the function run faster with static vars, or should I just keep all the queries?

Comment: Benchmark it and see for yourself. That's the best test you can do.

Comment: If the data is not changing, having it quickly available in php code is going to be faster. No overhead for queries.

Comment: Of course, running a query once and storing the result tends to be faster than running the same query 20 times. But if the ID is the only thing that changes, I have the impression that could just run *one* query with a wider `WHERE` clause. No code, no way to tell.

Comment: If you're trying to speed up your code, the first thing to do is run a profiler on it so you can see exactly which bits are slow. Otherwise you may end up spending lots of time tweaking stuff that doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll get to work with benchmarking & profiling :)